# Broadcast array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to reshape array of size (3,1) to (3,) with following code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.random(size=(4,3,1))
a[1]=a[1].reshape(3,)
```

But getting following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,1)
```

how to solve it.

Comment: Why are you using index-based assignment? `a[1]=a[1].reshape(`?

Comment: It's a need of my another long program, which is not possible to post here.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. You say you want to reshape `a`, so something like `a = a.reshape(3,)` makes the most sense. That is how you reshape an array. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: from (4,3) i want to make (4,3,1)

Comment: ... OK then use `.reshape(4,3,1)`... no?

Comment: Please check @Hunter answer below

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand, your array is consist of array of array (`a.shape = (4,3,1)`). 
I do understand that `a[1].shape = (3,1)` seems to be not so different to `a[1].shape = (3,)`, the program language however doesn't understand that way `((3,1) != (3,))` which means `(3,1)` and `(3,)` are totally different, since `a[2],a[3]` remain having `shape = (3,1)`, every array within an array of array must have the same shape (3,1). Therefore, you need to reshape all the array at once or alternatively make a copy of `a[1]` to another variable and reshape this variable instead.

```
a = a.reshape(4,3)
```

and use `a[1]`

alternatively:

```
b = a[1]

b = b.reshape(3,)
```